# Power series with decimal and arbitrary powers

Tags: series-expansion

Is there a way to make Mathematica do a series of the form:

```
 Series[ E^{\beta}$ , {x, 0, 1}]
```

I have noticed that

```
 Series[E^x^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}]
```

work but

```
 Series[E^x^(.5), {x, 0, 1}]
```

does not. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I have tried things like

```
  Assuming[{\bet>0},Series[ E^{\beta}$ , {x, 0, 1}]]
```

which hasn't helped.

Comment: `Rationalize` the expression, e.g., `Series[E^x^(.5) // Rationalize[#,0]&, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @BobHanion - Thanks but that doesn't seem to work for an arbitrary variable like \beta...?

Comment: What result do you expect for arbitrary beta?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - For arbitrary beta, not necessarily anything, but I have tried things like Assuming[\beta>0,Series[....]] and that didn't help.

Comment: That did not answer my question. I understand you have in mind, say, the symbol beta. What I do not know is what result you expect `Series[Exp[x^beta],{x,0,1}]` to deliver. I am looking for a response along the lines of "something + somethingElse*x^somepower + O[x]^someOtherPower" but with the various somethings made explicit.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - oh, ok. I would expect if beta is real and > 0, and x is small $e^{x^\beta} $$\approx 1 + x^\beta$ and Mathematica would give me something along these lines.

Comment: There are a couple of impediments, one in theory and one in practice. The first is that such a result might not make sense for β<0, say (where an expansion of the exponential at infinity would perhaps be a better idea). The practical issue is that `SeriesData`, the encapsulated result of a (proper) `Series` expansion in Mathematica, only supports explicit Puisiux series. So exponents must be explicit rational numbers. This is motivated by a number of considerations such as need to do manipulations on them, need for an explicit ordering of terms, and the like.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a general note.

for the case of this function:

```
E^x^(1/2)
```

you have to note that the derivative of `E^x^(1/2)` at `x=0` is ComplexInfinity.

to show you that, the general series of a function is as follows:

```
Clear[f]
s = Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

if you set `f[x]` to your function it will result in ComplexInfinity.

```
    f[x_] := E^x^(1/2)
      s

(* ComplexInfinity*)
```

Many be you need to change the point that you are calculating the series about