# Series expansion for rational function with weird powers of variable?

Tags: series-expansion

Consider the following series expression:

```
Series[1/(a+b x^(1/3)+c x^(4/3)),{x,0,1}]
```

The result comes out appropriately:

> 1/a - b x^(1/3)/a^2 +b^2 x^(2/3)/a^3 - b^(3) x/a^4 + O[x]^(5/3)

In comparison with this, now consider the following series expansion:

```
Series[1/(a+b x^(Zeta[3])+c x^(1+Zeta[3])),{x,0,1}]
```

Here the function breaks down and gives back:

> 1/(a+b x^(Zeta[3])+c x^(1+Zeta[3]))

I wonder why the expansion works in the case of `1/3` but does not work for `Zeta[3]`? Is there a convenient way to obtain the expansion for the second case above? As always, the examples are oversimplified, so that the expansion is actually needed for expressions that are a lot bigger and unwieldy. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: From the documentation, Details and Options, first item: "Series can construct standard Taylor series, as well as certain expansions involving negative powers, fractional powers, and logarithms." For some explanation, see comments from [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51981/power-series-with-decimal-and-arbitrary-powers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zeta[3]` is not proper number. so I think you should apply with `Rationalize[Zeta[3], 0.01]` in the power position.

```
z3 = Rationalize[Zeta[3], 0.01];
Series[1/(a + b x^(z3) + c x^(1 + z3)), {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Wow, this works incredibly well as an approximation. Thank you!